# Parse runtime created file in makefile script

Tags: makefile

I am writing a makefile script which should be able to parse a file which is created by the same makefile. I am using following code to parse `$(FileName)` file. When I execute I see `**cat: InputFile:No such file or directory**`. This code works fine for already existed file, but not working if file is not exist before I run make. Could you please suggest how can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Snippet from the Makefile -

```
test_connection:
. . .
//Create file named $(Filename)
. . .
$(call generate_list,$(FileName))

define generate_list
$(eval FILE_DATA= $(shell cat $(DIR)/$1);    \
$(foreach word, $(FILE_DATA),       \
. . .
endef
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are crossing boundaries. make parsing and processing happens before any rule bodies are run. target rule bodies are only run after that. So you can't create a file in a target rule body and expect it to be available for usage during make context (without using an included makefile but we'll get to that in a minute).

The simplest solution to this problem is simply to move the parsing out of make entirely and just do it in a shell (or other) script. This obviously doesn't work if you need the contents for some make-level decisions/etc. though.

The other possible solution is to use an included makefile and take advantage of the fact that when make rebuilds an included makefile it will restart its processing from the beginning (which then makes the contents of that makefile available from the start). To do this you would:

1. add an `include $(Filename)` line in your makefile
2. create a `$(Filename):` target with a rule to build it
3. parse the file (when it exists) in the top-level of your makefile
4. do what you need with the parsed data (in some makefile variables I assume) in the `test_connection` rule

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with makefile scripting. Here the file name would be different each time I run makefile. How can I say include $(Filename) then?

Comment: Where does the value of `$(Filename)` come from? And you can write literally that in your makefile if the variable has the correct value.

Comment: Thanks Etan, I got it resolved by splitting the code.